# Is it possible to create user defined roles with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB instance containing roughly 30 databases, each with a "client_data" collection. I want to give my client read privileges on this collection across all databases and no other collections. I want to write a script that does something like this:

```
mongoclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://admin:password@host/port")
rolenames = []
for dbname in mongoclient.get_databases():
   db = mongoclient[dbname]
   rolename = dbname + "role"
   rolenames.append[rolename]
   db.create_role(rolename, [ {resource: {db: dbname, collection: client_data}, actions: ["find"] } ])
```

and then

```
db.create_user("client", password, roles=rolenames)
```

I know that the create_user() function allows you to pass in predefined roles as an argument but is there a way to define new roles within pymongo as well?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can! Look at my example:

```
# assign your role name:
rolename = dbname + "role" 
  
db.command("createRole", rolename,
    privileges=[{"resource" : {"cluster" : True}, "actions" : ["inprog"]}],
    roles=[])
```

Comment: Did this work? Can you explain how this works? Where is the api documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the soultion that worked for me:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongoclient = MongoClient(mongos,
                     username=mongo_admin_user,
                     password=mongo_admin_pass,
                     authSource='admin')
mongoclient.admin.command("createRole", rolename,
               privileges=[{"resource" : {"cluster" : True}, "actions" : ["inprog"]}],
               roles=[])
```

In your case you forgot to add the client+admin_database+action

```
  'mongoclient.admin.command'
```

Please replace mongo_admin_user & mongo_admin_user with your mongo admin credentials.